# How to store Header in all splitted CSV files?

Tags: java

Below java code is to split a big .csv file into multiple .csv files. But how to store Header in all splitted files?

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class split {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String inputfile = "E:/Sumit/csv-splitting-2/Proposal_Details__c.csv";
            System.out.println("Input Path is :- " + inputfile);
            
            double nol = 100000.0;
            
            File file = new File(inputfile);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            
            int count = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                scanner.nextLine();
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);

            double temp = (count / nol);
            int temp1 = (int) temp;
            int nof = 0;
            if (temp1 == temp) {
                nof = temp1;
            } else {
                nof = temp1 + 1;
            }
            System.out.println("No. of files to be generated :" + nof);

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            for (int j = 1; j <= nof; j++) {
                String outputpath = "E:/Sumit/csv-splitting-2/";
                String outputfile = "File-2-Proposal_Details__c" + j + ".csv";

                System.out.println(outputpath + outputfile);
                FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter(outputpath + outputfile);

                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);
                for (int i = 1; i <= nol; i++) {
                    strLine = br.readLine();
                    if (strLine != null) {
                        out.write(strLine);
                        if (i != nol) {
                            out.newLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                out.close();
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't trust your spellchecker with "bellow". It is a word, yes. No, it is not the one you want.

Comment: This is basic looping stuff, you state below you are a novice to java, but presumably - from the amount of code above - not a novice to coding. Write out some pseudo code to do what you want in your language of choice and then transpose that into java.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first line is the header, you can have a `String header;` that will get the read of the first line, eg: `header = br.readLine();`.

On your for loop for `nof` (which I assume means `number_of_files`), you always add the header as the first line when you create a new file.

---

It would be something like this:

- before your for-loop, you just save the header on a variable

  - `String header = br.readLine();`
- you have 2 for-loops, one that creates a file, the other one that write each line to the newly created file

  - Inside the first for loop, right after you create the file, you just write the header to it: `our.write(header);`

General tips:

- use variable names that makes sense. `nol`, `nof`, `j`... none of them make sense, you can pretty much call them `numOfLines`, `numOfFiles` and `currentFile` for example.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I will be very much thankful if you kindly rectify the code, because I am novice in java coding.  I didn’t understand what to add in which line. Please Help me.

Comment: We are not supposed to give you the answer but rather help you find it. Nevertheless, I've edited my answer to include more info and some steps to be followed. Hope you can find the solution yourself =)